# What is "armtech daemon"?

Tags: tcp, netstat

I ran a `netstap -p tcp` on my machine (A macbook) and noticed a number of entries for something called `localhost.armtechdaemo`. Searching the web doesn't really give me anything useful.

Does anyone know what this is?

*Edit:*

Mystery solved. Running `lsof -i|grep armtech` gives the following:

```
ruby      19934 troelskn    7u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a084dd599      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon (LISTEN)
ruby      19934 troelskn    8u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a0431e821      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon->localhost:59101 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ruby      20202 troelskn    7u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a084dd599      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon (LISTEN)
ruby      20202 troelskn    9u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a027e69b1      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon->localhost:60640 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ruby      25215 troelskn    7u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a084dd599      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon (LISTEN)
ruby      25215 troelskn   10u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a00664b41      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon->localhost:56512 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ruby      30121 troelskn    7u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a084dd599      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon (LISTEN)
ruby      30121 troelskn   11u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a08eb89b1      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon->localhost:55730 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ruby      32818 troelskn    7u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a084dd599      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon (LISTEN)
ruby      32818 troelskn   18u  IPv4 0xeb92ec3a04a40691      0t0  TCP localhost:armtechdaemon->localhost:52797 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Port 9292 also happens to be the default port for the ruby web application framework [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which I use from time to time. The system must automatically assign the "armtechdeaemon", based on the IANA list.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault!  From our FAQ: Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.  As your question doesn't appear to meet that criterion, it will likely be migrated to superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, I had to do quite a bit of digging on it to figure this one out. It's not a well known port. Even still I found little to nothing about who Rohan Story is or what ArmTech is. I also found a few other services used the port as well so they are something to look into for you.

[**IANA**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)
*Port 9292*: ArmTech Daemon
*Assignee*:
Rohan Story
rohan@aurema.com

**Also associated:**
Port 9294: ARMcenter HTTP Service
Port 9295: ARMcenter HTTPS Service

From [msterminalservices.org](http://www.msterminalservices.org/software/Monitoring-&-management/ARMTech-for-Citrix/Comments/)

> ARMTech for Citrix is a workload management solution for Citrix
>   optimization. It works with Citrix Presentation Server software to
>   extend the system management capabilities of the Microsoft Windows
>   2000 and Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server operating systems.
>   ARMTech’s workload management capabilities give you the power to
>   control how applications and users consume valuable server resources,
>   including CPU and real and virtual memory. ARMTech manages every
>   process on the system and ensures equal distribution of server
>   resources, while protecting against OS starvation. So you can add more
>   users and applications without compromising service levels.

**Possible Services:**
 - [ArmTech Daemon](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)
 - [EMC2 (Legato) Networker or Sun Solcitice Backup (Official)

 - QuickTime Streaming Server](http://www.adminsubnet.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/iana/1860)

Comment: Strange indeed. Rohan Story is listed with an email `rohan@aurema.com` - That domain redirects to Citrix. So maybe ArmTech has something to do with Citrix.

Comment: It looks like it does: http://www.msterminalservices.org/software/Monitoring-&-management/ARMTech-for-Citrix/Comments/ - I wonder what the heck that is doing on my laptop though. To my knowledge, I'm not running any Citrix software.

Comment: Well I added it to the answer. Thanks for finding that one! Not quite sure why you would be seeing that if you don't run any Citrix Software.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Will Beninger's answer, a list of ports and common service names that it maps to, which tools like `netstat` usually reference is in `/etc/services`.  This is from my Linux (CentOS 6) box, but I believe its the same on Unix:

```
$ cat /etc/services  | grep 9292
armtechdaemon   9292/tcp                # ArmTech Daemon
armtechdaemon   9292/udp                # ArmTech Daemon
```